# I'm a new DM and have never played a tabletop RPG before. Any basic tips or strategies?

Tags: dnd-5e, new-gm

I am DMing for my family (a total of 7 other people) and have never played D&D or any other Tabletop RPG before. We will be playing D&D 5e. I know a lot of the basics from listening to The Adventure Zone podcast and reading various posts here. I also only have the player manual. I do not yet have the Dungeon Master's Manual or the Monster Manual. Are there any tips or ideas anyone can give me for our first campaign on Saturday?

Comment: I'm voting to close as too broad; sorry, but your situation really calls for discussion, not focused Q&A. A forum may suit you better; we have [a list of those we recommend](http://meta.rpg.stackexchange.com/q/5449/23970). I'll note that one of those we list is our own [chat], which could be an excellent start. You'll need 20 reputation to hat there, so I've thrown you the +5 I can. Welcome to the site, the hobby, and I hope to see you in chat!